# Not getting the correct JSON format from pulled API data

Tags: python, json, api, append, json-deserialization

I am trying to get this output into the correct JSON format. Unfortunately, that isn't really working out. All the data from an API pull is stored in a list which I then read in order to refine it and only get the data I need.

```
def refine_data():
    with open("api-pull.json", encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print('JSON loaded correctly')
        
        
        with open('REFINEDapi-pull.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as REFINED:
            for s in range(len(json_data)):
                
                if 'lat' in json_data[s] and 'lng' in json_data[s]: #if coordinates exist
                    
                    json.dump({
                        'name' : json_data[s]["name"],
                        'latitude' : json_data[s]["lat"],
                        'longitude' : json_data[s]["lng"],
                        'status' : json_data[s]["status"]["online"],
                        'address' : json_data[s]["address"],
                        'reward_scale' : json_data[s]["reward_scale"]
                        }, REFINED, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Small sample of my current output:

[image]

Sample of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Sample of what I am trying to accomplish]

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to get or what isn't working for you.

Comment: @coppereyecat I am sorry. Pretty new to StackOverflow. I added a link to a screenshot showing the incorrect JSON format I am getting.

Comment: What format are you trying to get? what's the problem with your output?

Comment: Although I suspect the issue is you are dumping one object at a time, not the entire array.

Comment: I've added a picture of the result I am trying to get.

Comment: Get out of he habit of doing `for i in range(len(list)):` Use `for item in list:`

Comment: Please add the output, and desired output as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is to append the `dict`s you create to a list and then `json.dump()` the single list to the file:

```py
def refine_data():
    with open("api-pull.json", encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print('JSON loaded correctly')        
        
        with open('REFINEDapi-pull.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as REFINED:
            result = []   # start a list here
            for s in range(len(json_data)):
                if 'lat' in json_data[s] and 'lng' in json_data[s]: #if coordinates exist
                    result.append({
                        'name' : json_data[s]["name"],
                        'latitude' : json_data[s]["lat"],
                        'longitude' : json_data[s]["lng"],
                        'status' : json_data[s]["status"]["online"],
                        'address' : json_data[s]["address"],
                        'reward_scale' : json_data[s]["reward_scale"]
                        })

            json.dump(result, REFINED, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! This makes a lot more sense.